# What is the name of the widget that is used for showing tutorials about a frontend app

Tags: tutorial, widget

There are some sites I've been on where, the first time you visit it, it will show you a little tutorial.

The tutorial will have big round animations that encircle a button and say something like "Click this button to add an item to your shopping cart!" and then you click Next and another button is highlighted, etc.

Is there an official name for this widget, or behaviour? I remember seeing a widget framework like "material-ui" contain aa widget like this but I don't remember...

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it's called "Feature Discovery"

Answer (score 0):

Onboarding / Features / Intro / App  ----  + ---- Tutorial / Guide / Overview / Walkthrough 
 
Seems most precise names are "Onboarding Tutorial", or "App Walkthrough".